# Cannot highlight code inside a toggleable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a blog post and of course I can write directly the html/css/js of the page.

In a particular post I will include several snippets of python code and thus I want to make those snippets toggleable. For that I put them inside a div and I play around the div's style display.

When I hit the button that shows the div, the code appears but then hightlight.js fails to highlight it at all.

Here is a minimal example of the html I would expect to work but is not working.

```
<div style="background-color:#F0F0F0;padding:5px"><button onclick="toggleCode(event, 'etapa0')">code</button></div>
<div style="display:none" id="etapa0"><pre><code class="python">from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
</code></pre></div>

<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
<script>
function toggleCode(evt, id) {
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "";
        hljs.highlightBlock(document.getElementById(id));
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

I have also tried to force `highlight.js` to apply the highlighting inside the function `toggleCode` but without success.

Comment: For me it seems, the JS code is not running after you press button, so it's don't apply JS.

Comment: That makes sense but I do not know how to fix that.

Comment: `style.display = ""`, `""` is not a valid value for the display property

Comment: @Raul Sauco what should it be then?

Comment: @RGS its working fine https://fiddle.jshell.net/3onf72pj/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the src url, try to add ***https:*** in the beginning

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign an empty string as the value of the css `display` property, which is not a valid value.

Change that to any of the valid values, you can see  a list of them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). In the following snippet I changed `""` to `"block"` and the code works fine.

```js
function toggleCode(evt, id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    hljs.highlightBlock(document.getElementById(id));
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
div#container {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <button onclick="toggleCode(event, 'etapa0')">code</button>
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="etapa0">
    <pre>
        <code class="python">from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
<script>

</script>
```